# unable to access vuex store property in safari. code is working fine in Chrome

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, safari, vuex

I am desperately needing some help with vuejs vuex store. it is working absolutely fine in chrome but in safari store property is not being picked up. basically I have stored a user object in Vuex store as follows: -
[here is the image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRWhs.png)

[here is the image of within component where I am trying to access the property from store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMprF.png)

[here is the image of when axios call is made and within response I am triggering the mutation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8wFi.png)

```js
state:{
    user:{},
    student:{}
    },
    
mutations:{
    setUser(state,payload) {
        state.user = payload;
        },
        
    setLoggedIn (state,payload) {
        state.isLoggedIn = payload;
        },
    
    setStudent(state,payload){
        state.student = payload;        
        }
        
        },

 getters:{
 
    isStudent: state => {
 
    if(state.user.user_type === 'student') {
     return true;
   }
   }
 
 }
```

I am calling the mutation from inside the login component whilst executing axios call request and setting the user and student through appropriate commit from the component.
However, when I am trying to access the user property inside the component, it works fine for Chrome but it is not working for Safari. Here is how I am calling for state user property inside the component: -

```js
computed:{
       
     computedStatus(){

                return this.$store.state.isLoggedIn;

            },
        computedUserType(){
                return this.$store.state.user.user_type;
        },
        isUserStudent(){
            return this.$store.getters.isStudent;
        }

    }
```

The property `isUserStudent` is used inside the component and is a dependency to further functionalities. This property is assessed correctly and as expected inside Chrome/Firefox, but in safari it is not being assessed. I am really puzzled what's going on here and hope that someone can support please

Comment: We need to see the rest of the code that calls the mutations. Since the `isStudent` getter will return `True` only if `user.user_type` is set, most likely this is a race condition where the getter is firing before the mutation that sets `user`. Even better if you can make a sandbox for us to test with.

Comment: Inside the axios call where I am getting the backend to provide student details, this is the extract of response where I am setting the mutation .... this.$store.commit('setStudent',{
                        student:response.data.data,

                    }); Please note that code is working fine in Chrome and in Firefox and I can see that in the console and vuex store in Chrome dev mode... but these store properties are not being picked up in Safari...

Comment: Please update the question - code is hard to read in comments. Also please don't use images of code in your question.

Comment: Hi Match, thank you for your help - appreciate it. I am sorry I am bit new to posting questions and still getting my head around. I have posted 3 images of the code which can be read better I hope. Please check

Comment: Don't post images of code please - use the code blocks